# How to store BIG int values

Tags: c#

What would you use if you had to hold numbers bigger than the ulong type can hold (0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615)? For instance measuring distance between planets or galaxies?

Comment: When you measure the distances between galaxies, you don't use meters any more :-)

Comment: Yes exactly. Then unit becomes `light years` if am not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For values which only require up to 28 digits, you can use [`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx). The way it's designed, you don't encounter the scaling issue you do with `double`, where for large numbers the gap between two adjacent numbers is bigger than 1. Admittedly this looks slightly odd, given that `decimal` is *usually* used for non-integer values - but in some cases I think it's a perfectly reasonable use, so long as you document it properly.

For values bigger than that, you can use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another alternative is to just use `double` and accept that you really *don't* get a precision down to the integer. When it comes to the distance between galaxies, are you really going to have a value which is *accurate* to a metre anyway? It does depend on how you're going to use this - it can certainly make *testing* simpler if you use a nicely-predictable integer type, but you should really think about where the values are going to go and what you're going to do with them.

Comment: Wait, you mean (long)**one trillion** + 1 will not result what is expected of that?

Comment: Just curious but does BigInteger have a MaxValue? The documentation seems to suggest it doesnt

Comment: the docs say bigint stores values from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which is smaller than the max value of ulong http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @iConqueror: The link you posted is for SQL Server's `bigint`. It does not have anything to do with C#'s `BigInteger`.

Comment: @Sayse: Given that it's "arbitrarily large", what would `MaxValue` mean?

Comment: @iConqueror - One of the examples in the documentation link provided gives an answer of `6277101735386680762814942322444851025767571854389858533375` which is far outside of the value you suggested. Jon - I was just curious about if there is any limits to this type

Comment: @AgentFire: Whoops - I meant `double` rather than `long`. Will fix.

Comment: @Sayse This may be an interesting thread http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/97980/any-document-which-says-exactly-what-range-of-numbers-are-net-bigintegers-desig

Comment: @iConqueror - Do you already know the answer to your own question? I don't want to spam this answer any more.

Answer (score 1):

I rather doubt you need to have integer types to store something like the distance between the galaxies. To my knowledge very large integer values are required in few cases like (demonstrative) encryption. For these cases, you can use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.100).aspx).

I think you should use floating point types (e.g. [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)) for purposes like one you described.